# Push is not working

Tags: javascript

After reading data with the help of for Each loop. Data is populating successfully.
I am trying to push objects in an array named test Data but it fails. Push is not working.
Below is my code.

```
$scope.testData=[];     
data.content.forEach(function(column) {
    var objects = {
        ip: "",
        user: "",
        date_created:""
    };
    objects.ip = column.ip;
    objects.user = column.username;
    var d = new Date(column.created);
    var a = d.toUTCString();
    objects.date_created = a;
    testData.push(objects);
});
$scope.safeApply(); 
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: where is the push?

Answer (score 2):

you should assign it to $scope ,try this

```
$scope.testData.push()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you assigned your array to the `$scope` object, trying to interact with `testData` direct will not work.

You need to change the line

`testData.push(objects);`

to

`$scope.testData.push(objects);`

and that should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for it.

```
$scope.testData = data.content.map(function(column) {
    var d = new Date(column.created);
    return {
        ip: column.ip,
        user: column.username,
        date_created: d.toUTCString()
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a 'test' with your code and it works:

```
$scope = {};
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.content = [{
    column: 1,
    ip: '192.168.123.544',
    created: new Date(),
    username: 'username'
}];
$scope.testData=[];
$scope.data.content.forEach(function(column) {
    var objects = {
        ip: "",
        user: "",
        date_created:""
    };
    objects.ip=column.ip;
    objects.user=column.username;
    var d = new Date(column.created);
    var a =d.toUTCString();
    objects.date_created=a;
    $scope.testData.push(objects);
});
console.log($scope.testData);
```

IF you want help, please paste the error massage;

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is that you have an array assigned to `$scope.testData` but you try to push to`testData`. This is not valid, and you have to keep your variables consistent. Let's clean up your code a little while we're at it.

```
$scope.testData=[];     
data.content.forEach(function(column) {
  $scope.testData.push({
    ip: column.ip,
    user: column.user,
    date_created: (new Date(column.created)).toUTCString()
  })
});
```

I would also consider changing `date_created` to camel case if you can, but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

if you see at line no 1 you declared an array $scope.testData = [];

so you need to use $scope.testData.push(objects)